# JavaScript: Deep Copy Image() Object

Tags: javascript, object, deep-copy

I have this object merging function:

```
function merge( obj1, obj2 )
{
    var result = {};
    for( var prop in obj1 )
    {
        if( obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop) )
        {
            if( 'object' === typeof obj1[prop] && 'object' === typeof obj2[prop] )
            {
                result[prop] = merge( obj1[prop], obj2[prop] );
            }
            else
            {
                result[prop] = obj2[prop];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result[prop] = obj1[prop];
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

The purpose of this function is to merge two objects into one, overriding the values of obj1 with those of obj2, if exists.

It works fine with most objects, however when I try to use it to merge two `Image()` objects, I'm thrown into an infinite loop. For example:

```
merge(new Image(), new Image())
```

results in:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I think it has something to do with the object's events, but I'm not sure.
Why do you think this is this happening, and how can this function be improved to fix this issue?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by merging two `Image` objects?

Comment: Why not use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)?

Comment: @MattBall I'm trying to merge two objects that have `Image` objects as one of their property

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara how can I use cloneNode to merge two objects and override values?

Comment: @YoavKadosh You could add a case where if the property value is a Node, you use that to copy the element.

Comment: @YoavKadosh why did you accept epascarello's answer if Alexander O'Mara's solution is the one you used?

Comment: @MattBall because epascarello explained why i'm thrown into an infinite loop, and that's part of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is null is an object so you are calling merge for all the nulls.

Second there is a property

```
ownerDocument
```

So you are looping over that...